# Apache POI throws -60 Error on cell with recursive formula. Can this be resolved or worked around

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I created a simple spread sheet to test this problem.  A percentage is computed at the top of the spread sheet.  Below the sum of a different column of numbers includes a computation of the sum total times the calculated percentage (A recursive formula).

This works fine in EXCEL.

In POI when the cell is computed it throws an undocumented FormulaError code (-60 ).

Is there a way to determine WHAT this error code is and how if to work around it / fix it?

Code:

```
    try {
        Session session = getSession();
        AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

        /**
         * creates an {@link HSSFWorkbook} the specified OS filename.
         */
        // Read the Excel template from the local hard drive
        String filename = "c:\\temp\\RecurssionTest.xls";
        // Create the control number and format

        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(filename));
        wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
        //Get the row and cell (zero index)
        int rindex = 0;
        int cindex = 0;
        //Get the Notes Fields worksheet
        Sheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
        //String fields[] = {"Position1","Position","PositionWC","Positionprefix","raterwc","Client_Name","State","Client_Division"};

        cellSetValNum(ws, rindex, cindex, 120);

        // Write the output to a file
        String excelOutput = "C:\\temp\\UpdatedRT.xls";
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelOutput);
        wb.write(fileOut);

        System.out.println("Formula Errors are: ");
        FormulaError fevals[] = FormulaError.values();
        for (FormulaError formulaError : fevals) {
            System.out.println("formula error val: " + formulaError.getCode());
        }


        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        evaluator.evaluateAll();
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
            System.out.println("processing sheet: " + sheet.getSheetName());
            for(Row r : sheet) {
                for(Cell c : r) {
                    if(c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {

                        System.out.println("Recalcing: "+r.getRowNum()+c.getColumnIndex() + "in "+ sheet.getSheetName());
                        System.out.println("Cell Type before is: "+c.getCellType());
                        //System.out.println("Cell value before is:" +c.getNumericCellValue());
                        evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(c);
                        evaluator.evaluateAll();
                        System.out.println("Cell Formula is: "+ c.getCellFormula());
                        System.out.println("Cell Type after is: "+c.getCellType());
                        //System.out.println("Cell Value After is: "+c.getNumericCellValue());

                        if(r.getRowNum()== 11){
                            System.out.println("This cell has an error");
                            System.out.println("Cell Error Value is: "+c.getErrorCellValue());
                        }
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                }
            }

        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
start set cell num
0 120.0
End set cell num
Formula Errors are: 
formula error val: 0
formula error val: 7
formula error val: 15
formula error val: 23
formula error val: 29
formula error val: 36
formula error val: 42
processing sheet: Sheet1
Recalcing: 20in Sheet1
Cell Type before is: 2
Cell Formula is: A1*A2
Cell Type after is: 2

Recalcing: 100in Sheet1
Cell Type before is: 2
Cell Formula is: A3*A12
Cell Type after is: 2

Recalcing: 110in Sheet1
Cell Type before is: 2
Cell Formula is: SUM(A6:A11)
Cell Type after is: 2
This cell has an error
Cell Error Value is: -60
```

Comment: i didn't get your problem but try replacing *Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(filename));* with *Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filename));*

Comment: Changing the code to use WorkbookFactory still throws the same error.